# web application first run?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

i have starting my first web application with this  tutorial 
but we i deleted all the files that suggested by VS without web.config as the suggested below  in the videio , i go this when i run my program ? 
any suggestions ?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUx2Bdx68f4

Directory Listing -- /

```
Friday, December 06, 2013 02:42 AM        <dir> bin
Friday, December 06, 2013 02:32 AM        <dir> obj
Friday, December 06, 2013 02:32 AM        <dir> Properties
Friday, December 06, 2013 02:43 AM          478 Site1.Master
Friday, December 06, 2013 02:36 AM          340 Site1.Master.cs
Friday, December 06, 2013 02:37 AM          779 Site1.Master.designer.cs
Friday, December 06, 2013 02:42 AM        2,002 Web.config
Friday, December 06, 2013 02:32 AM        1,285 Web.Debug.config
Friday, December 06, 2013 02:32 AM        1,346 Web.Release.config
Friday, December 06, 2013 02:37 AM        4,290 WebApplication3.csproj
Friday, December 06, 2013 02:37 AM        1,086 WebApplication3.csproj.user
```

Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0

Comment: I have no  idea what you're asking, and I doubt anyone else does, either.

Comment: when i running my program in VS  i got this why? Or how can i deal with this Error

Comment: You get _what_? You didn't tell us what you got, did you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't have startup page.You can add a web page and set as startup item,then try again.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an error, this is the list of files in the directory

This page shows simply because you haven't got start page, try marking your start page by right clicking the aspx, "set as start page".

like this:

[image]